# What does the "Attempts" count on the Trophy screen mean?

Tags: achievements, sky-force-reloaded

The icons represent the level difficulty for that Trophy but I can't get what the "Attempts" count does represent. It can't be really counting the times when the player did encounter the boss because the numbers don't match. For example I've encountered Araneae Lebes shown in the below screenshot for much more than one time before earning the Trophy. So it has to be something else. Does anyone know it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It show how many times you fought the boss before successfully killing it without dying.